# System.Windows.Forms.ListView in powershell hide output

Tags: winforms, powershell, listview

With the following code

```
$listView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listView.View = 'Details'
$listView.Width = 300
$listView.Height = 300
$listView.Columns.Add('User Name')
```

DisplayIndex : 0
Index        : 0
ImageIndex   : -1
ImageList    : 
ImageKey     : 
ListView     : System.Windows.Forms.ListView, Items.Count: 0
Name         : 
Text         : User Name
TextAlign    : Left
Tag          : 
Width        : 60
Site         : 
Container    :

It outputs the above in the powershell console.
How can I hide this output.

It is interfering with me converting using this script in -noconsole mode https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5

Comment: $listView.Columns.Add('User Name')|out-null and [void] worked thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To suppress the output you can use out-null:

```
$listView.Columns.Add('User Name')|out-null
```

Also if you assign it to a variable, it suppresses the output:

```
$item = $listView.Columns.Add('User Name')
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `[void]` before any `.Add` method usually suppresses output:

```
[void]$listView.Columns.Add('User Name')
```